# Visibility order of transactions

Tags: postgresql

I have a question regarding a problem akin to memory barriers in C++.

Say that transaction T performs two updates - UPDATE 1 and UPDATE 2, using the default READ COMMITTED serialization level.

If a separate read-only statement sees the result of UPDATE 2, is a subsequent read-only statement *guaranteed* to see the results of UPDATE 1?

As an example, UPDATE 1 could be any of INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE on some records in a table, and UPDATE 2 could be INSERT'ing a single "dirty" record in a separate table to record that rows in the first table have been "messed with". If a statement sees that "dirty" record, is the next statement guaranteed to see the results of the first set of operations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is guaranteed. All modifications by a transaction become visible at the same moment, when the transaction is marked as "committed". Any other transaction that can see the results of that transaction can see *all* of its results.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe. What about the order of the read-only transactions though? If "statement 1" sees the results of the "modifying transaction", is a subsequent "statement 2" (in an implicit transaction other than statement 1's) guaranteed to also see the results of the "modifying transaction"? Basically, is there a guarantee of "read consistency" among serial, read-only transactions, such that Read Transaction 2 is guaranteed to see everything that Read Transaction 1 has seen, when Read Transaction 2 strictly "follows" Read Transaction 1?

Comment: Sure. A later transaction in a database session can always see what a previous transaction could see.